# Compose multiple picutures onto a single A4 page for printing

Tags: image-editor, printing

I've got a large collection of holiday photos I want to print off in small sizes to glue into a scrap book.

I'm after sizes smaller than 6x4 so visiting a standard print kiosk isn't an option. However I'm thinking that it would be easy to get an A4 page printed that contains all the photos I want and then cut it up after.

Therefore I'd like a software that would make it easy to import lots of photos (maintaining their aspect) and build a collage/montage that can be exported as an image and printed in A4.

I don't currently have a printer that is capable of photo prints, so it would need to export to a medium that I can take it to a kiosk in.

What would be the best tool to do this?

Comment: AFAIK ImageMagick can do that via its `montage` command, see e.g. [here](https://scottlinux.com/2011/08/13/create-photo-collage-in-linux/), full parameters [here](http://support.cs.nott.ac.uk/help/docs/image/ImageMagick/www/montage.html), also see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37709879/2533433) on our sister site. Not used it this way myself, hence just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

[ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) can combine several images into a signal image, with great control over the settings, by using the [montage](https://imagemagick.org/script/montage.php) command.

You can specify the size(s) of the image(s), the borders to apply between images, the resolution(s), text to annotate each image, etc. There is a learning curve but there is a lot of online help.

- Command Line (so can be used in batch mode)
- Free, Open Source & Gratis
- Cross Platform (Unix, Mac OS-X/iOS & Windows *including Portable Installation*)

An example command line *(From Pat David)*:

```
 montage -verbose -label '%f' -font Helvetica -pointsize 10 -background '#000000' -fill 'gray' -define jpeg:size=200x200 -geometry 200x200+2+2 -auto-orient P21603{65..70}.JPG ~/Dropbox/contact-dark.jpg
```

Modified to avoid errors on Windows this gives:

```
 montage -verbose -label '%f' -font Areal -pointsize 10 -background "#000000" -fill "gray" -define jpeg:size=200x200 -geometry 200x200+2+2 -auto-orient P21603*.JPG contact-dark.jpg
```

*Note the changed quote types and the font name change*

Pat gives a nice walk through of the command [here](https://patdavid.net/2013/04/using-imagemagick-to-create-contact.html) but there are lots of other recipes online.

Answer (score 0):

[XnView MP](https://www.xnview.com/en/) will make contact sheets for you. It allows you to specify the number of thumbnails per row and column. Fewer of each yields larger images on the page. It doesn't have individual settings per image, but it works.

Most of the better know (read as older, more mature) image viewers also provide this feature.